# Ask for example: A simple ring with zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

We know that a simple ring has characteristic either $ 0 $ or a prime $ p $. I am thinking about giving a concrete example of a simple ring **WITH** zero divisors.

I have found a reference talking about simple rings without zero-divisors:

https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/438A61A4C89B22ADF1E46E759C3A7E3D/S002557930000187Xa.pdf/div-class-title-simple-rings-without-zero-divisors-and-lie-division-rings-div.pdf

Comment: [DaRT search for simple rings having zero divisors](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=3&L=8). [DaRT search for simple rings with no zero divisors, other than division rings](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=3&H=8&L=2) (just for kicks.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A matrix ring $M_n(R)$ when $R$ is a simple ring, is also simple.
For instance one can take $R$ to be one's favourite field. Matrix rings
generally have zero divisors.